# Check tensorflow configurable attribute value (bazel build)

Tags: tensorflow, build, bazel, flags

I build tensorflow with this command:

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow:tensorflow_dll_import_lib
```

This target has a select in cmd:

```
genrule(
    name = "tensorflow_dll_import_lib",
    srcs = [":get_tensorflow_dll_import_lib"],
    outs = ["tensorflow.lib"],
    cmd = select({
        "//tensorflow:windows": "cp -f $< $@",
        "//conditions:default": "touch $@",  # Just a placeholder for Unix platforms
    }),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

This is a config section for windows:

```
config_setting(
    name = "windows",
    values = {"cpu": "x64_windows"},
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Now I'd like to know the exact value of "cpu" flag.
1) Is it possible to know it without running "bazel build"
2) How/where may I see its value, when running "bazel build"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cpu` config option is provided by bazel.
The default behaviour is, it is autodetected by bazel here:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/lib_cc_configure.bzl#L180
However, you can override the autodetected value using the `--cpu` flag.

You can learn more about how bazel uses configuration options here:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/configurable-attributes.html#example